# ArcSDE Feature View in a GeoDatabase other than the Feature's Database

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, spatial-database

here is the problem I have been struggling with:

We have our spatial features in an SDE enabled DB (call it DB1) and have a client DB which is SDE enabled as well (meaning geo-DB call it DB2) and have some non spatial tables too.

Without copying features & using spatial features from DB1, we would like to generate Spatial Feature Views in DB2.

Is that possible? What options do we have to come over this?

Thanks a lot in advance